# Can i say "Tree is fallen" as "considering "fallen" as an adjective instead of past participle which will make the sentence passive voice?

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives, participial-adjectives

Can i say "Tree is fallen" as "considering "fallen" as an adjective instead of "past participle" which will make the sentence passive voice?

I know we cannot say "Tree is fallen" refering to passive voice but Could i say "tree is fallen" or not,if I use "fallen" as an adjective? EG "Tree is fallen" here i am depicting "current state" instead of "passive voice".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no issue of "passive voice" here: *fall* is intransitive, so it has no passive.

*is fallen* must therefore be an adjectival complement.

This is possible, but unusual: *fallen* is fine as an attributive adjective (*a fallen tree*), but not common as a predicative adjective (*The tree is fallen*).

We are far more likely to say *The tree has fallen*: since this is "present <s>passive</s>perfect" it has present relevance, and so probably depicts a state resulting from an event.

Note that *Tree is fallen* is not a grammatical sentence in most circumstances: you need an article, as in my examples.

Comment: "present passive" did you mean "present perfect"?

Comment: Indeed I did, @JamesK. Thank you. Now corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer "Don't say '(The) tree is fallen'".

This is part of the usage of the word fallen,  [Cambridge dictionary notes](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fallen) that "fallen" is used "before noun".  Cambridge considers the sense of "a fallen tree" to be an adjective, but this adjective has usage restrictions.

[Lexico considers](https://www.lexico.com/definition/fallen) this sense to be part of the verb, and a participle. Lexico only allows for the senses of "having sinned" and "killed in battle" for the adjective. (And Lexico would allow for "the devil is fallen")

In either analysis, you should not say "The tree is fallen".

Comment: I  understood that saying "Tree is fallen" is wrong either way but kindly Correct me if I am wrong, is saying "devil is fallen" correct according to lexico?  As i could not find any sentence saying "devil is fallen" in you given link above.

Comment: It's not, but Lexico doesn't specify a restriction on the usage of the adjective, and so by default it is unrestricted.  In the sense of "having sinned", the word "fallen" can come after the verb.  For example "I contend that, for Eliot, neither woman is fallen" [source](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Translation_Authorship_and_the_Victorian/k82XCwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22woman+is+fallen%22&pg=PA170&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: Past participles can be used as adjectives in phrases like _we passed a fallen tree_ or _the devil is a_ [fallen angel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallen_angel#Christianity), but it would be more natural to say _The tree has fallen_ when making a statement about its condition.